# How to programatically detect if a DataForm is in edit mode

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0, wcf-ria-services, dataform

I'm using a DataForm in Silverlight 4.  Several DataForms, actually, and they share a common RIA Services context.  Here's the problem I'm having...

If I start editing a DataField in one of the DataForms, then click on a button that calls Context.SubmitChanges(), I get the following error:

```
�Entity 'foo' is currently being edited and has uncommitted changes. 
  A call to BeginEdit must be followed by a call to EndEdit or CancelEdit 
  before changes can be submitted.�
```

Note that the "Submit Changes" button is external to the DataForms and applies to the RIA Services context that is shared between the DataForms (which are each in separate tabs of a tab control).

I'd like to be able to avoid this problem by detecting, in code, when a DataForm is in editing mode.  When I'm in debug mode, I can see that the DataForm has properties such as `IsEditing` and `CanCancelEdit` that indicate that it is in editing mode, but these properties do not seem to be available for use in my code.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since none of the available properties provided the information I needed, I ended up creating my own private field (in the UserControl that contains the DataForm) called `_isEditing` which is initialized to "false". In the `DataForm.BeginningEdit` event handler I set it to "true" and in the `DataForm.EditEnded` event handler I set it to "false". I then created a read-only public property called `IsEditing` to make the value available externally.

Answer (score 3):

You can call DataForm.CommitEdit() before calling DomainContext.SubmitChanges() and avoid the error entirely.

Comment: True, but I had been considering giving the user the option of whether to commit or cancel the changes.

Comment: I'd imagine that's not an option you give them regularly. Typically things get committed when focus changes and I'd wager they'd hate you if you prompted them every time focus left one of the form fields. I'm pretty sure that in this case the focus change just hasn't been processed yet.

Comment: I had this same issue and calling .CommitEdit() was the solution for me

Answer (score 3):

I used the CommitEdit method on my datagrid (should be the same on DataForm) before I called SubmitChanges() in order to fix the problem with a one liner.

```
myDataGrid.CommitEdit(DataGridEditingUnit.Row, true);
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what `IsEditing` and `CanCancelEdit` are, they aren't documented.

However there is a `Mode` property that is `DataFormMode` enumeration, `ReadOnly`, `Edit` and `AddNew`.  There is also an `IsItemChanged` property which indicates if any actual changes have been made editing began.

Comment: Thanks for answering. I tried both of these properties, but they don't give me quite what I need. If you have started making changes to a field but have not made any previous changes, IsItemChanged still reports "false". On the other hand, if you move to a new record but have not started making any changes to it, Mode reports "Edit".

Answer (score 0):

I used this code just now to solve the issue I was having. This is located in my codebehind, when the Save button is clicked:

```
        bool editresult = true;
        this.FindChildrenByType<DataGrid>().ToList().ForEach(grid =>
        {
            editresult = editresult && grid.CommitEdit(DataGridEditingUnit.Row, true) && grid.IsValid;
        });

        if (!editresult)
        {
            _messager.Alert("There is a problem with one of the items shown on the screen. This will usually be highlighted in red.\r\nPlease correct the item(s) and try saving again.");
        }
        else
        {
            // Save changes
        }
```

DataGrid.CommitEdit(DataGridEditingUnit.Row, true) tells the datagrid to commit the row, the last boolean tells the grid to exit editing mode. This will return a true or false depending on whether the row should have exited editing mode. Normally in a grid where you are editing a row and there are validation errors, the grid won't let you exit editing mode by clicking another item, but this call will allow exit but return false. The DataGrid.IsValid checks all items in the grid to see if they are valid.